# ContentByQueryWebPart: Performance degradation due to non-guid field ref for a multi-list CBQ

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have webpart which inherits class which inherits from ContentByQueryWebPart. The problem I am getting is that when I add any field to CommonViewFields from ToolPart - it returns error to the ULS"ContentByQueryWebPart: Performance degradation due to non-guid field ref {fieldname} for a multi-list CBQ.".The result is generated correctly, but it affects performance. I tried assigning values these ways:

```
webpartObject.CommonViewFields = "Title"
webpartObject.CommonViewFields = "Title,Text"
```

Either way the result is returned correctly, but with performance degradation. Maybe anyone has any suggestions what could be the couse ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid this issue need to specify field `GUID` and type when setting `CommonViewFields`.

**For example**: CommonViewFields may be `"{52cd2f97-2c0c-40ec-9157-143834056e4e},Description,Note;"`

Answer (score 0):

La,

Try adding the following property to your CQWP definition:

```
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">Title;AnotherField</property>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can't do it this way, because I need to add it dynamically